# EOFException while connecting local SFTP server in Java code

Tags: java, sftp, openssh, ftp-client, sshd

Getting below exception in Java while connecting local SFTP server
It's not reproducible other similar setups. Username and password both are correct.
What could be the root cause of it? What environment settings trigger this?

````
        at com.jscape.filetransfer.FileTransferException.wrap(Unknown Source)
        at com.jscape.filetransfer.SftpFileTransfer.a(Unknown Source)
        at com.jscape.filetransfer.SftpFileTransfer.connect(Unknown Source)
        at com.jscape.filetransfer.SftpFileTransfer.connect(Unknown Source)
        at Aaab_ln.Um(FtpUtil.java:113)
Caused by: com.jscape.util.n.b: java.io.EOFException
        at com.jscape.util.n.b.a(Unknown Source)
        at com.jscape.util.n.c.a(Unknown Source)
        ... 4 more
Caused by: java.io.EOFException
        at com.jscape.util.X.b(Unknown Source)
        at com.jscape.util.h.a.f.a(Unknown Source)
        at com.jscape.inet.ssh.protocol.v2.marshaling.primitive.Uint32Codec.readValue(Unknown Source)
        at com.jscape.inet.sftp.protocol.marshaling.MessageCodec.read(Unknown Source)
        at com.jscape.inet.sftp.SftpFileService3.c(Unknown Source)
        at com.jscape.inet.sftp.SftpFileService3.c(Unknown Source)
        at com.jscape.inet.sftp.SftpFileService3.b(Unknown Source)
        at com.jscape.inet.sftp.SftpFileService3.actualStart(Unknown Source)```
````

Comment: You've missed out the top line of the exception.